# Prevent table joins on same column by mistake

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using MS SQL Server Management Studio for SQL queries. Sometimes I join two tables on same column, and it takes really long to execute that query. I can't notice this mistake sometimes and it consumes my resources.

My question is: Is there an option in MS SQL Server Management Studio which will warn me when I join two tables on same column?

```
select mov.*, code.Description from Movements mov
inner join Codes code on code.CodeID = code.CodeID
```

Comment: as far as i know, there is no warning for such things. happens to me from time to time too. especially copy&paste errors.

Comment: The best thing to do here is pay more attention to your work. Coding is all about details anyway, so that should be a routine thing to do :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you press CTRL+L to display the estimated execution plan you can noticed a red icon in "Nested Loops" operator, also a warning is displayed "No Join Predicate".

See the image below. I simulate your example on AdventureWorks2014 database by joining HumanResources.Employee & Person.Person. The second example shows a mistake. 
Unfortunately nothing, besides that.

[image]